# Intune Restore specific configuration using Graph API

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I have used IntuneBackupAndRestore Poweshell Grpah Module to back up all the Intune configuration,
My need is to restore the configuration but not everything, eg. want to restore compliance policy that too one particular compliance policy, been going through this article (https://github.com/jseerden/IntuneBackupAndRestore), but could not find any solution.

If any of them could help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [Invoke-IntuneRestoreDeviceCompliancePolicy.ps1](https://github.com/jseerden/IntuneBackupAndRestore/blob/master/IntuneBackupAndRestore/Public/Invoke-IntuneRestoreDeviceCompliancePolicy.ps1#L33).

It gets all Device Compliance Policies here and restores the Device Compliance Policy via loop.

You should set a conditional statement to get the particular policy you want to restore.

Then you can restore only this one particular compliance policy.